# MarkLogic json:transform-from-json with multiple namespaces?

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

In MarkLogic, is it possible to use json:transform-from-json to convert json into XML with multiple namespaces? For example, how to convert

```
{
  options: {
    format: "xml"
  }
}
```

into

```xml
<options xmlns="xdmp:http-get">
  <format xmlns="xdmp:document-get">xml</format>
</options>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the example JSON that would indicate that those namespaces should be applied to the XML elements.

If you use [`json:transform-from-json()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/json:transform-from-json) the resulting XML will be in the `http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic` namespace.

```
<json type="object" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
  <options type="object">
    <format type="string">xml</format>
  </options>
</json>
```

You would then need to transform that XML in order to get those elements in the desired namespaces. One way to do that would be with a recursive typeswitch function:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace j = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic";
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
 at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

declare function local:convert($node as node()) as item()* {
  typeswitch($node)
    case attribute() return ()
    case element(j:json) return local:convert($node/node())
    case element(j:options) return element {fn:QName("xdmp:http-get", $node/local-name())} {local:convert($node/node())}
    case element() return element {fn:QName("xdmp:document-get", $node/local-name())} {local:convert($node/node())}
    default return $node
};

let $json := '{
  options: {
    format: "xml"
  }
}'

return local:convert(json:transform-from-json( $json ))
```

However, if you are attempting to construct the XML in order to build options for [`xdmp:document-get()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get), you might that it is easier to specify the options using a `map:map` instead of the XML form.

> Options with which to customize this operation. You can specify options as either an XML element in the "xdmp:document-get" namespace, or as a `map:map`. The options names below are XML element localnames. When using a map, replace the hyphens with camel casing. For example, "an-option" becomes "anOption" when used as a map:map key.

If you have the JSON object, you can select the `options` property and then use `fn:data()` or [`xdmp:from-json()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:from-json) to atomize the `options` object-node as a map:

```
fn:data($json//options)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on using map:map. It is indeed a much easier route.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, its not documented or easy, but its not secret.
Look at the source in Modules/MarkLogic/json/custom.xqy

There are many more custom parameters then are documented.  The 'interesting' ones allow you to override individual methods used for the transformation.
Example:  when using the custom strategy, you can set overrides.
The following are the defaults, you can change them.

```
map:put($c , $json-custom:element-qname-from-json-name  , json-custom:element-qname-from-json-name#2 ),
map:put($c , $json-custom:attribute-qname-from-json-name  , json-custom:attribute-qname-from-json-name#2 ),
```

Replace the function  'json-custom:element-qname-from-json-name'  with your own -- you can use whatever logic you want, given the configuration object and the current json field name, return the full QName.

The 'build in' function you can pull from the above file (it is not obscucated).  As of version 9.0 this looks like:

```
declare %private function json-custom:element-qname-from-json-name( $config as map:map , $json_name as xs:string? ) as xs:QName
{

   json-custom:qname( map:get( $config , $json-custom:element-namespace ) ,
                      map:get( $config , $json-custom:element-namespace-prefix ) ,
                      if(map:get($config , $json-custom:camel-case)) then  json-custom:from-camelCase($json_name) else $

 };
```

This can get very tricky to get right.   I recommend a combination of custom transformation followed by xml post processing (using xquery or xslt).

THe tricky part is that you don't get much 'context' when going from JSON to XML.
JSON does not have node ancestors or ordering.  All you get is a single field name.  If you can map to the desired QName from that, then its easy.  For example you can create a map of json names to QNames and put that in the config along with your custom function.

Often the requirements are more difficult, hence recommending you just try to 'get it close' with the configuration then post process.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your valuable insight for MarkLogic internals.